# How to completely fill a cell with a picture in a docx file using Python

Tags: python, docx

How do I use the entire space in a cell so that a picture fully covers it? I am trying to do this with Python in docx format. I have tried the following, but it results in an error:

```
chart_cell = row_charts[i]
image = Image.open(chart)

# Assuming some margin, you can adjust this value
margin = Pt(2)

# Calculate the available space for the image
available_width = chart_cell.width - margin * 2
available_height = 50  # Set an approximate value for the available height

# Resize the image to fit the available space
image.thumbnail((available_width, available_height))

# Calculate the positioning to center the image within the cell
left = (chart_cell.width - image.width) // 2
top = (available_height - image.height) // 2

chart_cell.paragraphs[0].clear()
chart_cell.paragraphs[0].add_run().add_picture(chart, left=Inches(left), top=Inches(top))
```